# How to set vue prop type to Array of User Class using typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to know if there is way to make my component only accept array of User class.

```
@Prop({ required: true, type: () => Array }) readonly user: Array<User>;
```

Above code accepts all arrays.

Comment: How does the above it accept all arrays? At compile time typescript will reject code that assigns an incompatible type. If you mean the decorator's `type` option, that's not a type at all, it's a value.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The problem is specific to Vue, more precisely, vue-property-decorator . TS prop type isn't checked outside the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prop type can be checked with custom validator:

```
@Prop({
  required: true,
  validator: prop => Array.isArray(prop) && prop.every(item => item instanceof User)
}) readonly user: Array<User>;
```

TypeScript is structurally typed, `Array<User>` doesn't require an array to be an instance of `User` class.

The purpose of `Array<User>` is to assert prop type inside the component, it preferably should be `readonly user!: Array<User>`.

Due to limitations of vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator class components, TypeScript cannot guarantee type safety for props at compilation time. Vue composition API can be used for strictly typed TypeScript components.

Comment: Thank you. Will have to look at composition API then.

Comment: You're welcome. As for composition API, see https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#definecomponent